# Isomorphism of the fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fundamental-groups

Given two complex algebraic varieties $X$ and $Y$. 
If there exists a birational proper morphism $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ 
then a Theorem of Grothendieck (SGA.X) say that $\pi_1^{et}(X)\cong \pi_1^{et}(Y)$.
Is it possible to obtain the same isomorphism for the topological fundamental group?
What conditions i have to imposse to get this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The MO discussion was for smooth varieties. The singular case I think is just false, since links of singularities are no longer simply connected. However, coming up with specific examples would require some work.